# Fastest and efficient way of creating file in .NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, makefile

I've an arraylist having 30000 items in it, what's the best way of creating a text file on the fly from an ASP.NEt page? Currently I'm using the code below but it times out with large data,

```
Using fileStr As New FileStream(sFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
 Using writer As New StreamWriter(fileStr)
   writer.WriteLine("Error Messages")
   For d As Integer = 0 To ar.Count - 1
      writer.WriteLine(ar(d).ToString())
      sErrMsg += "<tr><td class='errgrid'>><td class='errgrid'>" + ar(d).ToString() + "</td><tr>"
   Next
   writer.Close()
 End Using
 fileStr.Close()
End Using
```

Comment: ArrayLists are already evil by themselves, but put 30,000 items in any collection and it'll end up on the Large Object Heap, and that spells death in ASP.Net.  It'll work in testing your dev machine, but crash intermittently after you deploy.

Comment: If you're using a 'using' statement you don't need writer.Close() or fileStr.Close(). Just thought I'd throw that out there.

Comment: Also, writing 30,000 items to a html page is _bad_ usability.

Comment: Regardless of how fast you make this process, does it seem like a good idea to be doing it from a web page, on the web server? Couldn't you request the file creation from the web page and offload the effort to another machine or process? Do it asynchronously and free up the web server resources.

Comment: I know this is not an answer but could doing it asynchronously help in a way here?

Comment: Thanks Joel, I have updated my code to include your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume sErrMsg is a String variable. You really want to change that into a StringBuilder.

Comment: Also I'd changed the way it's working, as Joel said writing 30,000 items to an html page is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Well i think this is an easy way:

```
Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(path)
        Dim info As Byte() = New UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes("This is some text in the file.")

        ' Add some information to the file.
        fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length)
        fs.Close()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Well first off I'd say take this out of the ASP .Net `Page` and put it as something that runs on the server. Then create that file on the server then just have the user download the file or do whatever you need to do with it.